# SQL Query Help: select random employee of the month

Tags: sql, linq, random, query-optimization

Could any one show me how to get record from this statement

- Select random employee which is not an employee of the month in the last x months

Table Employee
ID
EmployeeName

Table EmployeeOfTheMonth
ID
EmployeeID
MonthStartedDate
MonthEndedDate

Thank you very much

Comment: See http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm on Selecting a random row.

Comment: Using Linq? (based on your tag)

Comment: Employee of the month is RANDOM at your company??? lol

Comment: @Deviant lol , should keep everyone happy ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
select top 1 id from employee as emp 
where not exist(
    select top 1 * 
      from employeeofthemonth as em 
      where em.id = emp.id and dateadd(m, -6, getdate()) < monthendeddt )
order by newid()
```

... or something close to that. i didn't run the sql, but on mssql server, this should be about right.

Comment: Seems like he wanted something in Linq.

Comment: What are the performance implications of this query? Looks as if it could become a bit of a bottleneck as the number of records increase.

Answer (score 0):

Modification of last answer, i prefer  to use IN statment

```
DECLARE @xMonth INT
SET @xMonth = 3
```

SELECT TOP 1 ID
FROM Employee
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT EmployeeID 
FROM EmployeeOfTheMonth
WHERE DATEADD(m, -@xMonth, GETDATE()) < MonthEndedDate)
ORDER BY NEWID()